# How do i add permissions to this roles?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using this api to create group wso2 is 5.9.0
https://localhost:9443/scim2/Groups

Payload-

{
    "displayName": "s2ic"
}

Answer (score 0):

In IS 5.9.0 adding permission to the role using SCIM is not supported. But You can use the [SOAP service](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/managing-users-and-roles-with-apis/#addrole) to achieve it.

There is a discussion going on in this [architecture thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/architecture@wso2.org/msg17924.html) to support in the IS 5.10.0